# Подключения файла css к php

Tags: php, css

Здравствуйте.
Я чайник в PHP, мне нужно подключить стиль css с этим простым кодом

```
body{
    background-color: rgb(255,128,0);
}
```

вот как я это исполнил

```
include "style.css";
```

Работает не совсем так как хотелось бы, выводит просто код который в нутри css документа. Помогите, буду признателен ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP генерирует HTML страничку и уже ее отсылает пользователю. PHP не может использовать сами css классы, так что нужно добавить тег link что бы сгенерированная HTML страничка могла ссылаться на стили и скачать их уже у пользователя по ссылке.

Что бы добавить этот тег достаточно вывести его с помощью `echo`:

```
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>";
```

Comment: @pavel1787mego я не успел исправить, там были повсюду двойные кавычки и PHP думал что это PHP код между ними, вместо выводимого текста. Теперь должго работать.

Answer (score 0):

Что бы вывести код из документа используйте функции чтения из файла.

Например:

```
<style>
<?php echo file_get_contents("style.css"); ?>
</style>
```

Но знайте, это не лучший вариант, поскольку могут возникнуть трудности с путями внутри css файла, так что я бы рекомендовал вам стандартные способы подключения стилей:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
```

или

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
@import url("style.css");
</style>
```